# rfe in R's caret package giving error as : task 1 failed - "argument 1 is not a vector"

Tags: r, r-caret, feature-selection

I have a `training_predictors` set with **56 columns**, all of which are `numeric`. `training_labels` is a `factor` vector of `0` and `1`.

I am using following list as subset sizes to be tested.

```
subset_sizes <- c(1:5, 10, 15, 20, 25)
```

Following is the list of modified `rfFuncs` functions.

```
rfRFE <- list(summary = defaultSummary, 
              fit = function(x, y, first, last, ...) {
                  library(randomForest)
                  randomForest(x, y, importance = first, ...)
              }, 
              pred = function(object, x) predict(object, x), 
              rank = function(object, x, y) {
                  vimp <- varImp(object)
                  vimp <- vimp[order(vimp$Overall, decreasing = TRUE),,drop = FALSE]
                  vimp$var <- rownames(vimp)
                  vimp
              }, 
              selectSize = pickSizeBest, 
              selectVar = pickVars)
```

I have declared the control function as:

```
rfeCtrl <- rfeControl(functions = rfRFE, 
                      method = "cv", 
                      number = 10, 
                      verbose = TRUE)
```

But when I run `rfe` function as shown below,

```
rfProfile <- rfe(training_predictors, 
                 training_labels, 
                 sizes = subset_sizes, 
                 rfeControl = rfeCtrl)
```

I am getting an error as :

```
Error in { : task 1 failed - "argument 1 is not a vector"
```

I also tried changing the vector `subset_sizes`, but still no luck. What am I doing wrong?

Update : I tried to run these steps one by one and the problem seems to be with the `rank` function. But I am still unable to figure out the problem.

**Update:** I found out the problem. `varImp` in rank function is not containing `$Overall`. But it contains columns with names `0` and `1`. Why is it so? What does `0` and `1` signify (both column values are exactly same, by the way)? Also, how can I make `varImp` to return `$Overall` column? [as a temporary solution, I am creating a new column `$Overall` and attaching it to `vimp` in `rank` function.]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `0` and `1` as factor levels is problematic since those are not valid R column names. In your other SO post you probably would have received a message about using these as factor levels for your output.

Try using a factor outcome with some more informative levels that can be translated into valid R column names (for class probabilities).

Comment: Hi could please show an example, my class attribute has two levels both of them are characters lets Tumor and Normal. Still I am getting the same error. The rest of the code is same. I have 200 numeric columns and the last column 201 is Class.

Comment: Thanks a lot Max! I am a huge fan of your book and all of your practical suggestions to solve a machine learning problem!

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution for this same issue to fit a logistic regression model in rfe using caret. The solution as below:

```
glmFuncs$rank <-function (object, x, y){

  vimp <- varImp(object, scale = FALSE)
  loadNamespace("dplyr")

  vimp <- vimp$importance %>% 
    mutate(var=row.names(.)) %>%
    arrange(-Overall)

   vimp <- vimp[order(vimp$Overall, decreasing = TRUE), ,drop = FALSE]
   vimp
}
```